# 'Compile Error' - 'Object required' VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to print a document however I am receiving the error

> 'Compile Error' - 'Object required'

and then it highlights the line

```
 Set previousPrinter = objWord.ActivePrinter
```

I am using the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim previousPrinter
    Dim objWord As New Word.Application


    Set previousPrinter = objWord.ActivePrinter
    objWord.ActivePrinter = "Followprint"


    On Error GoTo CLOSE_WORD_APP 'error handling to ensure there will not be any orphaned and invisible Word application left

    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open("test.docx")

    doc.Variables("refBook").Value = Me.txtRef.Text
    doc.Fields.Update
    doc.Save

    objDoc.PrintOut
    ' Restore the original printer
    objWord.ActivePrinter = previousPrinter

    doc.Close

CLOSE_WORD_APP:
    objWord.Quit SaveChanges:=False



End Sub
```

Comment: why `Set previousPrinter = objWord.ActivePrinter`? According to [Application.ActivePrinter property (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.activeprinter), `ActivePrinter` returns a `string`, so the line should be `previousPrinter = objWord.ActivePrinter`. No `Set`needed. Am I wrong? Actually, your variable `previousPrinter` should be a `string`type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActivePrinter` returns a string with the name of the printer, not an object. Therefore, declare `previousPrinter` as string and simply assign the result of `ActivePrinter` to it.

```
Dim previousPrinter as String
Dim objWord As New Word.Application

previousPrinter = objWord.ActivePrinter
objWord.ActivePrinter = "Followprint"
(...)
```

In VBA, the keyword `Set` is only used to assign an *object* to a variable (eg the result of the `Documents.Open`-function). If you use it when trying to assign anything that is not an object, the compiler (or the runtime) will throw the `Object required` error message.